# how to wrap two divs inside another div using css in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have a website in opencart, the homepage is default where it shows a code like

```html
<div id="content"> <?php echo $content_top; ?></div>
```

I added my own HTML code inside it like below:

```html
<div class="created">
this is some content
</div>
```

now the content I created is coming in the footer, am not able to find the default code for the page, I want the content to be placed below the slider in the page, so I created a parent div `main-div` for both the slider and my content, but as I don't have the code to the homepage i am not able to place the slider and my content inside the main div, I only know the class of the slider `slider-wrap`, is there anyway to force the two classes inside the `main-div` using css or javascript. please help. thanks in advance

Comment: you have to add sample running code with full idea.

Comment: @aviboy2006 i want to put two divs inside another div, using css, an alternate for <div class="main"> <div class="first"></div>  <div class="second"></div></div>